# Efficient way to implement wait-for-enter method for the TextField? (JavaFX)

Tags: java, javafx, eventhandler

I´m currently working on a Textadventure and decided to move it from the console to JavaFX with scenebuilder. I´m using a TextView for output and a TextField for input.
This is how my Code looks:

```
public class Story implements Initializable {
    public Button startButton;
    public TextArea textArea;
    public TextField textField;
    public EventHandler mainplot;

    //On startButton pressed
    public void startGame() {
        setEventFilters();
        begin();
    }

    public void begin() {
        print("Welcome to the Adventure."); //print is a method for appending String to textArea
        print("You wake up in your room.");
        print("Fresh air blows through your window.");
        print("You get up. What do you want to do?");
        print("1. Drink from the magical can.");
        print("2. Go outside.");
        textField.addEventFilter(ActionEvent.ACTION, mainplot);
    }

    public void magicalCan() {
        ...
    }

    public void goOutside() {
        ...
    }

    public void setEventFilters() {
        //mainplotFilter
        mainplot = new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            public void handle(ActionEvent e){
                if(textField.getText().equals("1")) {
                    textField.removeEventFilter(ActionEvent.ACTION, mainplot);
                    magicalCan();
                }
                if(textField.getText().equals("2")) {
                    textField.removeEventFilter(ActionEvent.ACTION, mainplot);
                    goOutside();
                }
            }
        };
    }
```

The Code continues in the same scheme - more Eventfilters for decision and more methods for the storylines. Now let´s say I want to add multiple enterkey inputs within the storylines:

```
    public void begin() {
        print("Welcome to the Adventure.");
        //wait for enter to continue
        print("You wake up in your room.");
        print("Fresh air blows through your window.");
        print("You get up. What do you want to do?");
        //wait for enter to continue
        print("1. Drink from the magical can.");
        print("2. Go outside.");
        textField.addEventFilter(ActionEvent.ACTION, mainplot);
    }
```

What is the most efficient way to implement an Eventhandler or a waitForEnterkey() method that can be used across all the storyline methods?

Comment: Why the need for 20-30 event handlers? One handler that can make decisions based on the state of your storyline would be a better approach.

Comment: Do a simple `JavaFX` tutorial before you attempt this. Start [here](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/javafx/textfield.html). You don't understand how a `Textfield` works.

Comment: I clarified my question, please take a look.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a crude example of what you are attempting to do. This is asking questions and not telling a story but the programming ideas to do this are very similar.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 *
 * @author blj0011
 */
public class JavaFXApplication71 extends Application
{

    String[] questionBank =
    {
        "Connie has 15 red marbles and 28 blue marbles. How many more blue marbles than red marbles does Connie have?",
        "Connie has 15 red marbles and some blue marbles. She has 13 more blue marbles than red ones. How many blue marbles does Connie have?",
        "Connie has 28 blue marbles. She has 13 more blue marbles than red ones. How many red marbles does Connie have?"
    };
    String[] correctAnswer =
    {
        "28 - 15 = 13", "15 + 13 = 28", "28 - 13 = 15"
    };
    String[] answer1Bank =
    {
        "28 - 15 = 13", "28 - 13 = 15", "28 - 13 = 15"
    };
    String[] answer2Bank =
    {
        "15 + 13 = 28", "15 + 13 = 28", "28 - 15 = 13"
    };
    int currentQuestionCounter = -1;//Keeps up with what question is currently being asked

    TextArea storyScreen = new TextArea();
    TextField userInput = new TextField();
    Button btnStart = new Button();

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage)
    {
        storyScreen.setWrapText(true);//Wrap the text in the TextArea
        storyScreen.setEditable(false);//Don't allow useInput in the storyScreen

        userInput.setOnAction(actonEvent ->//Retrieve user Input on Enter pressed
        {
            TextField tempUserInput = (TextField) actonEvent.getSource();//get a reference to the userInput TextField.
            switch (tempUserInput.getText())//Switch on that input
            {
                case "1":
                    if (answer1Bank[currentQuestionCounter].equals(correctAnswer[currentQuestionCounter]))
                    {
                        storyScreen.appendText("\n\nYou got this right!");
                        btnStart.setDisable(false);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        storyScreen.appendText("\n\nYou got this wrong!");
                    }
                    break;
                case "2":
                    if (answer2Bank[currentQuestionCounter].equals(correctAnswer[currentQuestionCounter]))
                    {
                        storyScreen.appendText("\n\nYou got this right!");
                        btnStart.setDisable(false);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        storyScreen.appendText("\n\nYou got this wrong!");
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    storyScreen.appendText("\n\nYou have to enter a 1 or 2!");
                    userInput.setText("");
            }
        });

        btnStart.setText("Start");
        btnStart.setOnAction(actionEvent ->
        {
            btnStart.setText("Next");
            btnStart.setDisable(true);
            userInput.requestFocus();//Move the cursor to the userInput TextField
            getCurrentQuestionSetup(++currentQuestionCounter);
        });

        VBox root = new VBox();
        root.getChildren().addAll(storyScreen, userInput, btnStart);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }

    void getCurrentQuestionSetup(int currentQuestion)
    {
        if (currentQuestion < questionBank.length)
        {
            userInput.setText("");//reset the TextField
            storyScreen.clear();//reset the TextArea

            //Add new Question and answer to Textarea
            storyScreen.setText(questionBank[currentQuestion]);
            storyScreen.appendText("\n\n1: " + answer1Bank[currentQuestion]);
            storyScreen.appendText("\n2: " + answer2Bank[currentQuestion]);
        }
        else
        {
            storyScreen.appendText("\n\nYou have completed this story!");
            userInput.setText("");
            btnStart.setText("Start");
            btnStart.setDisable(false);
            currentQuestionCounter = -1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If I were doing this, I would have an `SQLite` database that stores my story in parts with the info about each part. I would create a `List` of objects of each story part. I would create a handler class to retrieve the correct story part.

Answer (score 1):

Add an "[ActionListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/ActionListener.html)"  to the text field. When the text field has focus and the user presses  <kbd>Enter</kbd>  an event will be fired. To retrieve the text use this code:

```
textField.getText();
```

and then you can match the text with your EventFilter you are utilizing.

Comment: I clarified my question, please take a look.